# How to remove HTML5 semantic markup from MVC3 project

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to remove HTML5 semantic markup from existing project?
I have some code that dont work if I turn on "HTML5 semantic markup" when creating project.
Same code is working if I turn off "HTML5 semantic markup".

[image]

thx

Comment: can you provide the code in question?

Comment: http://blogs.gokulnath.com/2012/02/26/EnableBrowserBackforwardButtonsAndBookmarkMVCAjaxActions.aspx

Comment: you can download solution from link above.

Comment: it work if HTML5 is turn off